# Retrieve Multiple Strings Out Of HTML TD, Delimit The Strings and Join Them With Loop of TD Elements?

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to learn how to use Beautiful Soup to get data from a website that has joined key strings into one block.

```
<html>
    <head>


        <center>
        <font face="arial" size="5">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#000066">
        
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#000066">

          <a href="/"><img height="50" width="540" src="/leftbar-quote.gif" border="0" usemap="#leftbar10b39c7"></a>
              <map name="leftbar10b39c7"><area href="/outside/multi.htm" coords="328,5,390,36" shape="rect">
              <area href="/index.htm" coords="254,5,322,37" shape="rect">
              <area href="#" coords="185,5,251,35" shape="rect" onclick="history.back(); return false;">
              <area href="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=q&sEmail=&part=Engine&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&name=AutoPartex.net&int=-1&uIMS=&userSearch=exact&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&ref=&userid=1000&email=&userClaim=&userLang=&userZip=&selleruserid=1000" coords="400,5,460,36" shape="rect">
              <area href="/buyerfaq.htm" coords="470,5,530,36" shape="rect">
              </map>


            </td>
            <td valign=top><div align="right"><img height="50" width="36" src="/result-rs.gif"></div></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
<td COLSPAN=2><table WIDTH="100%"><tr>
            <td width="10" valign="top"><img height="30" width="10" src="/trans4.gif"></td>
            <td width="90%">
            <b>
<div style='font-size:18pt; font-style: italic; color: white;'><b>Results sorted by <u>PRICE</u></b> <span class="small"><b>(Click on heading to re-sort)</b></span><br /></div><font color='#FFFFFF' face='Arial,Helvetica,Geneva,Swiss,SunSans-Regular' size='2'>Click back to modify your previous choice.<br>Most prices do not include extended warranties or shipping.<br>Not all displayed parts are interchangeable.  Please verify with the recycler that the part fits your auto.<br /></font></b></td><td valign=bottom align=center><table bgcolor="#e4e4e4"width=350 cellpadding=3 border=1 cellspacing=0><tr><td align=center><form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/search.cgi" style="display: inline"><input type= hidden name=userDate value="2005"><input type= hidden name=userModel value="Ford Focus"><input type= hidden name=userLocation value="USA"><input type= hidden name=userPreference value="price"><input type= hidden name=userZip value=""><input type="hidden" name="userPage" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="userInterchange" value="None"><input type="hidden" name="userDate2" value="Ending Year"><input type="hidden" name="userSearch" value="int"><input type="hidden" NAME="userClaim" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userClaimer" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userLang" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userLat" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userLong" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userCSA" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userMCO" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userAdjuster" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="userItem" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="hpsDate" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="hpsGroup" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="reqId" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="thirdMapType" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="vendUrl" VALUE="">
<input type="hidden" NAME="iCN" VALUE="">
<input type='hidden' name='limitYears' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='userIntSelect' value='711575'>
<input type='hidden' name='userVIN' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='vinSearch' value='0'>
<input type='hidden' name='userVINModelID' value=''>
<input type="hidden" name="uID" value=""><input type="hidden" name="uPass" value=""><table bgcolor="#e4e4e4" width=350 cellpadding=3 border=1 cellspacing=0><tr><td colspan=2 align=center>2005&nbsp;Ford Focus<br>Engine<br></td></tr><tr>
<td align=center>

    <font style="font-size: 10pt">Non-Interchange search for year:<br></font>
    <font style="font-size: 10pt"><b>2005</b><br><br></font>
<br>
<br><font style="font-size: 8pt"><a style="color:blue" href="/cgi-bin/search.cgi?userDate=2005&userModel=Ford%20Focus&userPart=Engine&origPart=&userPreference=price&userZip=&userLat=&userLong=&userVIN=&dbPart=300.1&userIntSelect=711575&userClaimer=&userClaim=&uID=&uPass=&userLocation=USA&userSearch=int">Click Here</a> to see All Interchange Choices </font>
</td>
</table></table></form>
</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr align=center>
    <td><a href='/cgi-bin/search.cgi?userSearch=exact&userPID=1000&userLocation=USA&userIMS=&userInterchange=%5B%7C%7Br&userSide=&userDate=2005&userDate2=2005&dbModel=27.20&userModel=Ford%20Focus&dbPart=300.1&userPart=Engine&sessionID=600000000000000000456918622&userPreference=year&userIntSelect=711575&userUID=0&userBroker=&userPage=1&iKey='>Year</a><br>Part<br>Model</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><a href='/cgi-bin/search.cgi?userSearch=exact&userPID=1000&userLocation=USA&userIMS=&userInterchange=%5B%7C%7Br&userSide=&userDate=2005&userDate2=2005&dbModel=27.20&userModel=Ford%20Focus&dbPart=300.1&userPart=Engine&sessionID=600000000000000000456918622&userPreference=miles&userIntSelect=711575&userUID=0&userBroker=&userPage=1&iKey='>Miles</a></td>
<td><a href='/cgi-bin/search.cgi?userSearch=exact&userPID=1000&userLocation=USA&userIMS=&userInterchange=%5B%7C%7Br&userSide=&userDate=2005&userDate2=2005&dbModel=27.20&userModel=Ford%20Focus&dbPart=300.1&userPart=Engine&sessionID=600000000000000000456918622&userPreference=grade&userIntSelect=711575&userUID=0&userBroker=&userPage=1&iKey='>Part <br> Grade</a></td>   <td>Stock#</td>
    <td>US<br>Price</td>
    <td>Dealer Info</td></tr><tr><td>2005<br>Engine Assembly<br>Ford Focus</td><td><a href=""><img width="100" hspace="3" align="middle" onclick="return popupImg('seller=2013&partGUID=2013-1-282435&vehicleGUID=2013-1-V18432&display=2005%20Ford%20Focus%20Engine%20Assembly-Stock%23%2010286')" src="http://wsimgoh.autopartex.net/2013/2015/10286/2013_18432_05_thumb.jpg"></img></a>ZX4,2.0,EFI,FATO,FWDRUNSGREAT</td><td align=right>&nbsp;</td><td align=center>&nbsp;</td><td>10286</td><td align=center>$350550</td><td><A HREF="http://www.LaPointAuto.com" target="_top">LaPoint Discount MIDW</A> USA-OH(Holland)  <A HREF="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=g&sEmail=shawn@LaPointAuto.com&email=&part=Engine%20Assembly&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&stockNum=10286&price=350550&desc=ZX4%2C2.0%2CEFI%2CFATO%2CFWDRUNSGREAT&name=LaPoint%20Discount%20MIDW&url=http://www.LaPointAuto.com&int=-1&broker=0&recycler=0&selleruserid=2013&miles=-1&condition=-1&userid=1000&uIMS=&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&userClaim=&userLang=">Request_Quote</A> 419-865-2329 / 800-845-0270 <A HREF="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=i&sEmail=shawn@LaPointAuto.com&email=&part=Engine%20Assembly&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&stockNum=10286&price=350550&desc=ZX4%2C2.0%2CEFI%2CFATO%2CFWDRUNSGREAT&name=LaPoint%20Discount%20MIDW&url=http://www.LaPointAuto.com&int=-1&broker=0&recycler=0&selleruserid=2013&miles=-1&condition=-1&userid=1000&uIMS=&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&userClaim=&userLang=">Request_Insurance_Quote</A><br><a target=_blank href="http://appcgi.autopartex.net/cgi-bin/applet.cgi?sid=2013&brf=&bds=&bsr=price&pin=&pyr=2005&pmd=Ford%20Focus&ppt=Engine%20Assembly&ppr=350550&pst=10286&pgr=&bty=WEB&bem=&bzp=&ses=600000000000000000456918622" onclick='window.open(this.href,this.target,getPrm()); return false'><img src='/images/LiveChat_space.gif' border=0></a></b></td></tr><tr><td>2005<br>Engine Assembly<br>Ford Focus</td><td>TESTED,2.3L,5MT,08/04,FWD,+CORE</td><td align=right>&nbsp;</td><td align=center>&nbsp;</td><td>E94764</td><td align=center>$1500</td><td><A HREF="http://www.ParadiseAutoParts.com" target="_top">Paradise Auto Parts-ELITE</A> USA-MD(Elkton)  <A HREF="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=g&sEmail=mdriver@complete-recycle.com&email=&part=Engine%20Assembly&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&stockNum=E94764&price=1500&desc=TESTED%2C2.3L%2C5MT%2C08%2F04%2CFWD%2C%2BCORE&name=Paradise%20Auto%20Parts-ELITE&url=http://www.ParadiseAutoParts.com&int=-1&broker=0&recycler=0&selleruserid=2843&miles=-1&condition=-1&userid=1000&uIMS=&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&userClaim=&userLang=">Request_Quote</A> 888-811-5051/410-620-5051 <A HREF="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=i&sEmail=mdriver@complete-recycle.com&email=&part=Engine%20Assembly&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&stockNum=E94764&price=1500&desc=TESTED%2C2.3L%2C5MT%2C08%2F04%2CFWD%2C%2BCORE&name=Paradise%20Auto%20Parts-ELITE&url=http://www.ParadiseAutoParts.com&int=-1&broker=0&recycler=0&selleruserid=2843&miles=-1&condition=-1&userid=1000&uIMS=&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&userClaim=&userLang=">Request_Insurance_Quote</A><br><a target=_blank href="http://appcgi.autopartex.net/cgi-bin/applet.cgi?sid=2843&brf=&bds=&bsr=price&pin=&pyr=2005&pmd=Ford%20Focus&ppt=Engine%20Assembly&ppr=1500&pst=E94764&pgr=&bty=WEB&bem=&bzp=&ses=600000000000000000456918622" onclick='window.open(this.href,this.target,getPrm()); return false'><img src='/images/LiveChat_space.gif' border=0></a></b></td></tr><tr><td>2005<br>Engine Assembly<br>Ford Focus</td><td>175-175</td><td align=right>38,916</td><td align=center>A</td><td>FC6555</td><td align=center>$1250</td><td><A HREF="http://www.DonsSportcar.com" target="_top">Don's Sportcar</A> USA-CO(Pueblo)  <A HREF="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=g&sEmail=parts@DonsSportcar.com&email=&part=Engine%20Assembly&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&stockNum=FC6555&price=1250&desc=175-175&name=Don's%20Sportcar&url=http://www.DonsSportcar.com&int=-1&broker=0&recycler=0&selleruserid=3776&miles=38.916&condition=-1&userid=1000&uIMS=&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&userClaim=&userLang=">Request_Quote</A> 800-332-3649 <A HREF="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=i&sEmail=parts@DonsSportcar.com&email=&part=Engine%20Assembly&dbPart=300.1&dbSubPart=&model=Ford%20Focus&dbModel=27.20&year=2005&stockNum=FC6555&price=1250&desc=175-175&name=Don's%20Sportcar&url=http://www.DonsSportcar.com&int=-1&broker=0&recycler=0&selleruserid=3776&miles=38.916&condition=-1&userid=1000&uIMS=&seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&userClaim=&userLang=">Request_Insurance_Quote</A><br><a target=_blank href="http://appcgi.autopartex.net/cgi-bin/applet.cgi?sid=3776&brf=&bds=&bsr=price&pin=&pyr=2005&pmd=Ford%20Focus&ppt=Engine%20Assembly&ppr=1250&pst=FC6555&pgr=A&bty=WEB&bem=&bzp=&ses=600000000000000000456918622" onclick='window.open(this.href,this.target,getPrm()); return false'><img src='/images/LiveChat_space.gif' border=0></a></b></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body> </html>
```

This is the html text and structure. Here's what I actually need help with in terms of approach:

1. With no css decorators I'm not able to locate with traditional examples found using `xpath` or something like `selenium`.
2. I needed for text that's in a cell to be seperated into seperate strings.
3. Using BeautifulSoup I tried usings a few methods to get the text
4. After trying something like this I'm getting this error:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("./test.html"), "lxml")

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:

        tds = tr.find_all("td")

        try:
            result = str(tds[0].get_text())

        except:
              adjust =  ' '
              continue

        result = result.split(" ")

        result = str.replace('2005Engine', "2005Engine", "2005 ")  + str.replace('AssemblyFord', "AssemblyFord", "Engine Assembly ") + str.repl$

        strresult = ''.join(result)


        trs = soup.find_all('tr')

        for tr in trs:

               tds = tr.find_all("td")

               tds[0] = strresult

               tds.get_text()

               print(tds)
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "carpartbs5.find.td.py", line 33, in <module>
    tds.get_text()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1807, in __getattr__

    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get_text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Here is the flip-soup:

When I just print the `td`s, it replaces the first `td` using any array, however, whenever I try and just return text using the `get_text()` method from `BeautifulSoup`, it throws that error. The error seems to state that I have a problem calling a method on something that's not possible.

So I'm not really clear on lists and strings. I tried converting my list to an actual string towards the end and it does not work. I thought because I'm using a list that that's the reason why it cannot get the text. If so, is there a better way using `BeautifulSoup` to achieve the goal of:

1. Getting individual text out of these positions in each element
2. Join them in a nicely comma delimited string result?

Hopefully this helps, I don't have enough points to post pics or upload files. The last text is what my program spit out IF I DON'T TRY AND CALL A BEAUTIFULSOUP METHOD ON THE `td`s variable.

My code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("./test.html"), "lxml")

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:

        tds = tr.find_all("td")

        try:
            result = str(tds[0].get_text())

        except:
              adjust =  ' '
              continue

        result = result.split(" ")

        result = str.replace('2005Engine', "2005Engine", "2005 ")  + str.replace('AssemblyFord', "AssemblyFord", "Engine Assembly ") + str.repl$

        strresult = ''.join(result)


        trs = soup.find_all('tr')

        for tr in trs:

               tds = tr.find_all("td")

               tds[0] = strresult

               print(tds)'
```

What Was Returned - A Sample:

```
['2005 Engine Assembly Ford Focus ', <td>139K</td>, <td align="right">\xa0</td>, <td align="center">\xa0</td>, <td>0232</td>, <td align="center">$800</td>, <td><a href="http://someurl.com" target="_top">Chads Part </a> USA-FL(Jacksonville)  <a href="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=g&amp;sEmail=chadsparts@someplace.com&amp;email=&amp;part=Engine%20Assembly&amp;dbPart=300.1&amp;dbSubPart=&amp;model=Ford%20Focus&amp;dbModel=27.20&amp;year=2005&amp;stockNum=0232&amp;price=800&amp;desc=139K&amp;name=Chads%20Parts&amp;url=http://someurl.com&amp;int=-1&amp;broker=0&amp;recycler=0&amp;selleruserid=3566&amp;miles=-1&amp;condition=-1&amp;userid=1000&amp;uIMS=&amp;seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&amp;userClaim=&amp;userLang=">Request_Quote</a> 1-510-569-4845 <a href="/cgi-bin/quoteForm.cgi?type=i&amp;sEmail=chadsparts@someplace.com&amp;email=&amp;part=Engine%20Assembly&amp;dbPart=300.1&amp;dbSubPart=&amp;model=Ford%20Focus&amp;dbModel=27.20&amp;year=2005&amp;stockNum=0232&amp;price=800&amp;desc=139K&amp;name=Chads%20Parts=rs&amp;url=http://someurl.com&amp;int=-1&amp;broker=0&amp;=0&amp;selleruserid=3566&amp;miles=-1&amp;condition=-1&amp;userid=1000&amp;uIMS=&amp;seqNum=600000000000000000456918622&amp;userClaim=&amp;userLang=">Request_Insurance_Quote</a><br/><a href="http://someurl.com/cgi-bin/applet.cgi?sid=3566&amp;brf=&amp;bds=&amp;bsr=price&amp;pin=&amp;pyr=2005&amp;pmd=Ford%20Focus&amp;ppt=Engine%20Assembly&amp;ppr=800&amp;pst=0232&amp;pgr=&amp;bty=WEB&amp;bem=&amp;bzp=&amp;ses=600000000000000000456918622" onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,getPrm()); return false" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="/images/LiveChat_space.gif"/></a></td>]
```

Just to reinforce:

I only want to get the text out of these elements to be delimited with commas into one string that I can work on again as I prep to write a csv file.

Year, Part, Car Make, Car Model, Description, Miles, Part Grade, Stock #, Price, Dealer Name, Country, State, City, Phone

- The first cell and the last are the hardest to figure out how to get the strings out, into a list and back to a string in that same order above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have 3 times "2005 Engine Assembly Ford Focus" (as is in your html example), you can do it this way:

1. Since HTML included is not well structured you should take the last table from it.

```py
table = soup.findAll('table')[-1]
```

2. Next you should take all rows except first (header row)

```py
tr = table.findAll('tr')[1:]
```

it will be array. You can loop through rows afterward.

3. And last you should take first `td` tag from each row. I will do it only for the first row.

```py
td = tr[0].td
```

4. Now you will have something like this:

```
<td>2005<br/>Engine Assembly<br/>Ford Focus</td>
```

Unfortunately I don't know pretty way to process this string.
For example you can use this method:

```py
td = tr[0].td.children
```

You will get array with all words and tags and process it as you want.